# How to send Keys.Tab as a parameter to a function

Tags: selenium, parameters, key, send

I have a code as below:

```
void someFunc(){
driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("Nodes_AddNodeDescriptionInput"))).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
}
```

which sends a key Tab to the xPath mentioned.
But i want to avoid driver...details in that someFunc(), so I want to have a code which replaces the above code with the below one.

```
if(!sendKeyboardKeysByXpath("Nodes_AddNodeDescriptionInput", Keys.TAB)) {
printError("Failed to send the Tab key.");
return(false);
}
```

Def for sendKeyboardKeysByXpath:

```
public static boolean sendKeyboardKeysByXpath(String xPathKey, CharSequence... textToType) {
printLogs("Calling sendKeyboardKeysByXpath with values: " + xPathKey + ", " + textToType);
try {
printLogs("Typing '"+ textToType + "' to " + xPathKey);
if(!checkElementPresenceByXpath(xPathKey)) {
printFunctionReturn(fn_fail);
return(false);
}   
driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(xPathKey))).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(xPathKey))).sendKeys(textToType);
} 
catch(Throwable t) {
ErrorUtil.addVerificationFailure(t);
printError("sendKeysByXpath: Exception occurred while typing keys.");
printFunctionReturn(fn_fail);
return(false);
}
return(true);
}
```

How to send the Keys.Tab as a parameter. I am getting garbage value in sendKeyboardKeysByXpath function

Answer (score 0):

Use `Keys.TAB.name()` it will write TAB

So in your log method it would be `textToType.name()`

Comment: Update to last version of the API and you'll have it